# Navbar dropdown is not leading to the given link

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

I am trying to make a navbar work on nuxt with Buefy components. I actually have dropdown component that I use in this navbar and having problem with. This is my navbar component in nuxt

```
<b-navbar-item class="has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    <b-dropdown hoverable aria-role="list">
        <a slot="trigger" class="navbar-item" role="button">
        <span>Academics</span>
        <b-icon icon="menu-down" />
        </a>
        <template v-for="(each, index) in academicsArray">
        <b-dropdown-item :key="index" aria-role="listitem" tag="nuxt-link" :to="each.link">
            {{ each.text }}
        </b-dropdown-item>
        </template>
    </b-dropdown>
</b-navbar-item>
```

required array

```
academicsArray: [
    { link: '/academics/pre-primary', text: 'Pre Primary' },
    { link: '/academics/1', text: 'Class 1' },
    { link: '/academics/2', text: 'Class 2' },
    { link: '/academics/3', text: 'Class 3' },
    { link: '/academics/4', text: 'Class 4' },
    { link: '/academics/5', text: 'Class 5' },
    { link: '/academics/6', text: 'Class 6' },
    { link: '/academics/7', text: 'Class 7' },
    { link: '/academics/8', text: 'Class 8' },
    { link: '/academics/9', text: 'Class 9' }
]
```

In layout directory, I have landing.vue file where i called `website-navbar`

Now when i use this landing layout in pages, and i click on dropdown item, it doesn't lead me to that link. Also localhost:3000/academics/1 is working, so i have configured my router correctly, but dropdown item isn't leading me to that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using example used here https://buefy.org/documentation/navbar

```
<b-navbar-dropdown label="Academics" class="is-hoverable">
  <template v-for="(each, index) in academicsArray">
    <b-navbar-item :key="index" :href="each.link">
      {{ each.text }}
    </b-navbar-item>
  </template>
</b-navbar-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `has-link` in the `b-dropdown-item`.
See the doc here: https://buefy.org/documentation/dropdown#links-within

Comment: It didn't worked but i went with this example, https://buefy.org/documentation/navbar
thanks for the help anyways.